# Why doesn't `x != x.isdigit()` work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to make a loop that prompts the user to enter a valid string of digits, and has to ask the user until they enter a correct input.

I think I have the right idea here but I am not entirely sure how to correct the wrong input.

```
def c():
    x = input("Enter a String of Digits")
    while x != x.isdigit()
        i = input("enter correct data string")
    else:
        print("True")

c()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`str.isdigit()` returns a boolean (True / False), don't compare it with `x` itself, but just use the return value:

```
def c():
    x = input("Enter a String of Digits")
    while not x.isdigit():
        x = input("enter correct data string")
    print("True")

c()
```

- SyntaxError fixed: add missing `:` in `while ..:` line.
- `i = ...` changed to `x = ...`

Comment: oh I see what you mean, instead of just using X in the while loop use the boolean (true in this case). Is this the same with all thing pertaining to booleans?

Comment: @Phizy, I meant: `x` is a string, `x.isdigt()` is a boolean object. So comparing them always return `False`; causing body of the while loop is never executed.

Comment: @Phizy imagine that the user enters "abc". Then "abc" != "abc".isdigit() is comparing "abc" != False. "abc" does not equal False, and neither would any string. "123" does not equal False either.